# Access-Violation in Release Mode

Tags: c, debugging, release, declaration, access-violation

I wrote a program in C, using visual Studio. My program run correctly in debug but when I switch into release mode, I face access-violation error via running the program with one Matrix.
The structure of my program is as below:

```
int main()
{
//some declaration and memory allocation
while(true)
{
//include algorithm with memory allocation
....
//releasing the allocated memories
// point I
//Point II
}}
```

as you see there are two points, there is a Matrix(`double ** RX`), which there is no different whether I free its memory or not. I mean as my program run many times in while loop, there is no leak memory whether I release this memory or not. But on the other hand I have another matrix(`double ** bit_error_rate`), which I use it to find out my results in program. In release mode, as I tried to have access to this matrix a face error:

```
fout = fopen("results.txt","w+");
        for(i = 0 ; i < EbN0dB_Len ; i++)
        {
            for(i1 = 0; i1 < iteration; i1++)
                fprintf(fout,"%lf\t",bit_error_rate[i][i1]);
            fprintf(fout,"\n");
        }
        fprintf(fout,"\n");
```

before this part I use this matrix just once:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < iteration ; i++)
    {
        tot_error_matrice[t][i] = tot_error_vecteur[i];
        bit_error_rate[t][i] = tot_error_vecteur[i]/total_bits;         
    }
```

I checked what ever consider usual such as: initializing the variables and pointers, out of band access, dangling pointers(all pointers are either NULL or have a valid value). But now I have no result.

---

Edited:
As I commented all codes like `fprintf(fout,"%lf\t",bit_error_rate[i][i1]);` the program runs correctly, put I am not able to view the output.

---

Edited 2:
I found out that the problem must be with the last code segment, when `t` is equal 4 the exception occurs.

---

Edited 3:
I am completely confused with my own project:
1. there was a memory leak, which was not(Point 1)
2. A run-time error without any reason
3. I have 4 declaration which were related to this part:

```
double *  new_error_vecteur = (double*)malloc((iteration)*sizeof(double));
double *  tot_error_vecteur = (double*)malloc((iteration)*sizeof(double));
double ** tot_error_matrice = (double**)malloc(EbN0dB_Len*sizeof(double*));
double ** bit_error_rate    = (double**)malloc(EbN0dB_Len*sizeof(double*));
```

I have just changed their position and every ting get solved!!!

Comment: I think you meant "violated access" instead of "violent access".

Comment: Or rather _Access Violation_ ...

Comment: Please update the question to include all the relevant code. At the moment it's pretty much impossible to tell you what might be wrong.

Comment: to be honest, the code is very large and the relevant part is just this. the other parts are something around 694 lines with many function calls. I am looking for possible mistakes. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: debug mode - AFAIK (I don't use VC++) adds stack checking and automatic memory initialization.
You should check for suspect type casts and uninitialized variables/memory.
Did you activate a reasonable warning level?

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings.  Enable all the features of the CRT debug heap (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) and see if you catch anything in the debug build.  Try AppVerifier (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: The problem is just with "printf" function, in other referring to this variable, the code is working correct..don't you have any idea?

Comment: Use fclose to close the file when you've finished writing.

Comment: I used, but I did't write it here.